# How do I exclude results with the most recent date?

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and have been learning as I go by just Googling and experimenting. I am trying to get all workstation names, jobstream names, and valid from dates where there are duplicates in both the workstation and jobstream columns. I currently have the below query:

```
SELECT   T2.WORKSTATION_NAME,T2.JOB_STREAM_NAME,T2.JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM
FROM     (SELECT  JOB_STREAM_REFS_V.WORKSTATION_NAME,
                 JOB_STREAM_REFS_V.JOB_STREAM_NAME
          FROM     MDL.JOB_STREAM_REFS_V AS JOB_STREAM_REFS_V
          GROUP BY WORKSTATION_NAME,JOB_STREAM_NAME
          HAVING   COUNT(JOB_STREAM_NAME) > 1
          ORDER BY WORKSTATION_NAME,JOB_STREAM_NAME) T1
JOIN MDL.JOB_STREAM_REFS_V T2 ON T1.WORKSTATION_NAME = T2.WORKSTATION_NAME
                             AND T1.JOB_STREAM_NAME = T2.JOB_STREAM_NAME
```

This gives the below results which is what I'd expect:

```
WORKSTATION_NAME    JOB_STREAM_NAME     JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM 
-------------------------------------------------------------
STATION1            STREAMA             2015-04-26 
STATION1            STREAMA             2015-04-27 
STATION2            STREAMB             2016-04-05 
STATION2            STREAMB             2016-07-25 
STATION2            STREAMB             2016-09-05 
STATION2            STREAMB             2017-07-25 
STATION2            STREAMC             2016-09-21 
STATION2            STREAMC             2016-10-21 
STATION3            STREAMD             2016-08-08 
STATION3            STREAMD               
STATION3            STREAME             2016-09-04 
STATION3            STREAME
```

However I want to exclude the most recent entry for each workstation/jobstream based on the valid from dates and only return results with older valid from dates or with no valid from date, so that I only get the below:

```
WORKSTATION_NAME    JOB_STREAM_NAME     JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM 
-------------------------------------------------------------
STATION1            STREAMA             2015-04-26 
STATION2            STREAMB             2016-04-05 
STATION2            STREAMB             2016-07-25 
STATION2            STREAMB             2016-09-05 
STATION2            STREAMC             2016-09-21 
STATION3            STREAMD               
STATION3            STREAME
```

I'm at a total loss at this point and not sure how to approach this. I've tried using MAX to get the latest dates and show only everything older than that using WHERE but I could not get it to work, I'm not sure where to even place those statements in my query and there is a slight chance I am in over my head.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery gives you the `workstation_name`/`job_stream_name` pairs with more than one entry. On this base you select records. You can simply select the maximum date along in the subquery and exclude it in your main query. This is your query with the comparision of the `job_stream_valid_from` added:

```
select   
  t2.workstation_name,
  t2.job_stream_name,
  t2.job_stream_valid_from
from     
(
  select 
    workstation_name, 
    job_stream_name, 
    max(job_stream_valid_from) as max_job_stream_valid_from
  from mdl.job_stream_refs_v
  group by workstation_name, job_stream_name
  having count(*) > 1
) t1
join mdl.job_stream_refs_v t2 on t1.workstation_name = t2.workstation_name
                             and t1.job_stream_name = t2.job_stream_name
                             and max_job_stream_valid_from > t2.job_stream_valid_from
order by t2.workstation_name, t2.job_stream_name;
```

You could even remove the `having count(*) > 1` now that the last records per `workstation_name`/`job_stream_name` get excluded anyway. Which shows we can reformulate the task: Give us all entries that have a newer sibling. And that is simply:

```
select *
from mdl.job_stream_refs_v jsr
where exists
(
  select *
  from mdl.job_stream_refs_v newer
  where newer.workstation_name = jsr.workstation_name
    and newer.job_stream_name = jsr.job_stream_name
    and newer.job_stream_valid_from > jsr.job_stream_valid_from
)
order by workstation_name, job_stream_name;
```

Comment: That is amazing thank you so much, it looks so much simpler than what I have been working with and is much easier to follow!

Is it possible to also return matching entries where job_stream_valid_from is NULL?

Comment: I don't know how you want `job_stream_valid_from is null` applied in your query, but of course it's possible to add such condition to your query, e.g. `where job_stream_valid_from is null or exists (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with ANSI standard window functions.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT WORKSTATION_NAME, JOB_STREAM_NAME, JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM
FROM (SELECT jsr.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY jsr.WORKSTATION_NAME, jsr.JOB_STREAM_NAME) as cnt,
             MAX(jr.JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM) OVER (PARTITION BY jsr.WORKSTATION_NAME, jsr.JOB_STREAM_NAME) as max_JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM
      FROM MDL.JOB_STREAM_REFS_V jsr
     ) jsr
WHERE cnt > 1 AND JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM < max_JOB_STREAM_VALID_FROM
ORDER BY WORKSTATION_NAME, JOB_STREAM_NAME
```